# Multiple API endpoints based on environments

Tags: angular, environment-variables

I have tried including qa environment in Angular 2 apart from dev and prod so for that what I have done is created environment.qa.ts like this:

```
export const environment = {  
    production: false,
    envName: 'qa',
    apiUrl: 'qa api endpoint goes here'
};
```

and my environment.ts

```
export const environment = {  
    production: false,
    envName: 'dev',
    apiUrl: 'dev api endpoint goes here'
};
```

and in my angular cli.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "bam-ui"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "data",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.scss",
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
        "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
        "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts",
        "qa": "environments/environment.qa.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss",
    "component": {
    }
  }
}
```

and I tried `ng serve --environment=qa` which is still pointing to dev environment. I tried `ng serve --env=qa`, `ng serve --e=qa` etc. Is it even possible in Angular 2 to have more environment variables?

Comment: How do you know, it is still pointing to dev environment. In your service classes how are you initializing the apiUrl?

Comment: Can you post your code where you are using the environment variables?

Comment: In my urls.ts I'm using like this import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
export class URL{
    public static API_ENDPOINT=environment.apiUrl;} so that it can access api endpoint based on the environment I've selected. It still keeps pointing to dev